# AWS DynamoDB updateItem problems in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, swift4

I am trying to update an item in my dynamoDB noSQL database. Having some troubles implementing this in swift as there is no swift documentation yet.

I was able to create an item in the database successfully, updating an item seems to be a whole other monster.

Swift Code:

```
var updatedValue: AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
updatedValue.s = self.UserID

let dynamo: AWSDynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB()

let AddToHistory =  Users()
AddToHistory?._campany = self.CompanyTextBox.text!
AddToHistory?._personalSite = self.PersonalTitleTextBox.text!
AddToHistory?._facebook = self.FacebookTextBox.text!
AddToHistory?._linkedIn = self.LinkedInTextBox.text!
AddToHistory?._title = self.TitleTextBox.text!
AddToHistory?._bio = self.BioTextBox.text!

let updateInput: AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput = AWSDynamoDBUpdateItemInput()
updateInput.tableName = "myTableName"
updateInput.key = ["_userId": updatedValue]

    let updatedCompany = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedCompany?.s = AddToHistory?._campany

    let updatedFacebook = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedFacebook?.s = AddToHistory?._facebook

    let updatedLinkedIn = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedLinkedIn?.s = AddToHistory?._linkedIn

    let updatedPersonalSite = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedPersonalSite?.s = AddToHistory?._personalSite

    let updatedTitle = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedTitle?.s = AddToHistory?._title

    let updatedBio = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    updatedBio?.s = AddToHistory?._bio

    updateInput.expressionAttributeValues = [
        "_campany" : updatedCompany!,
        "_facebook" : updatedFacebook!,
        "_linkedIn" : updatedLinkedIn!,
        "_personalSite" : updatedPersonalSite!,
        "_title" : updatedTitle!,
        "_bio" : updatedBio!,
    ]

    updateInput.returnValues = AWSDynamoDBReturnValue.updatedNew


    dynamo.updateItem(updateInput).continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error == nil) {
            }

             return nil
        }
    )
```

Not getting any warnings or errors in the editor, however when I run the app and press the button which runs this code, I get this exception thrown:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '`- init` is not a valid
>   initializer. Use `+ defaultDynamoDB` or `+ DynamoDBForKey:` instead.'

Not sure what I am missing here, it must be something to do with the way I am initializing the dynamoDB object. Tried accessing a default method for init, but there is no such method. :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to consider using the object mapper api? Amazon does provide [swift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-dynamodb-objectmapper.html) for this, in addition to a [sample project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Swift)

Comment: Thanks, didn't occur to me to do that, I used the object mapper to create items, didn't realize if an item already exists it just replaced the values that are different. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *Jake.lange's* comment, I realized I could have used the object mapper that i used to create items to update them as well. Heres the code incase others run into this problem :)

```
   //db connection mapper
        let objectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

        //new instancer of User class
        let itemToUpdate:CheckaraUsers = CheckaraUsers()

        //populate
        itemToUpdate._userId = UserID
        itemToUpdate._firstName = FirstName
        itemToUpdate._lastName = LastName
        itemToUpdate._campany = AddToHistory?._campany
        itemToUpdate._facebook = AddToHistory?._facebook
        itemToUpdate._linkedIn = AddToHistory?._linkedIn
        itemToUpdate._personalSite = AddToHistory?._personalSite
        itemToUpdate._title = AddToHistory?._title
        itemToUpdate._bio = AddToHistory?._bio

        //save to dynamoDB
        objectMapper.save(itemToUpdate, completionHandler:{(error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
            }

            print("Saved Information!!!")
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition was wrong.

Change this:

```
let dynamo: AWSDynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB()
```

to:

```
let dynamo: AWSDynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.default()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).